# I can't run mongodb, even though I have followed most posts here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, mongodb

When I try `sudo mongod --port 27017` or `sudo mongod`, I have the error:

```sh
NonExistentPath, Data directory /data/db not found
```

So, I created `/data/db` with chmod 777 under `/Users/thiago/` and ran:

`sudo mongod --dbpath /Users/thiago/data/db`

But still getting the same error.

**Error Messages**:

$sudo mongod

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.824-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12590,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"C02T507NGTFJs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.829-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T19:58:39.831-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

$sudo mongod --dbpath /Users/thiago/data/db

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.205-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.207-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.208-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.208-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12614,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/thiago/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"C02T507NGTFJs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.208-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.208-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.208-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/thiago/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.211-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/Users/thiago/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.211-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.816-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444453:816494][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:53.896-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444453:896463][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.008-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444454:8614][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 6/4608 to 7/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.113-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444454:113155][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.177-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444454:177740][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.235-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444454:235869][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.235-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604444454:235985][12614:0x11da86dc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.283-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1072}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.284-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.332-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.333-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.333-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.333-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.338-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22184,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Soft rlimits too low","attr":{"currentValue":2560,"recommendedMinimum":64000},"tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.398-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.423-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/Users/thiago/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.444-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.445-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-03T20:00:54.445-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Why whenever I run the mongod command, do I get a log return?

Even though it worked in the second log, I continue with the return of that error when running the mongod:

```
DBException in initAndListen, terminating", "attr": {"error": "NonExistentPath: Data directory / data / db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file
```

My db config:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mydb_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        roles:
         - 'root'
        auth_source: admin
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mydb_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV["MONGODB_URI"] %>
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

When I try $mongod -v, I got:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.678-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.685-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.685-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22940,   "ctx":"main","msg":"file descriptor and connection resource limits","attr":{"hard":9223372036854775807,"soft":256,"conn":204}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":3251,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"C02T507NGTFJs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"systemLog":{"verbosity":1}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.686-03:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22940,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"file descriptor and connection resource limits","attr":{"hard":9223372036854775807,"soft":256,"conn":204}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.688-03:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23104,   "ctx":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","poolName":"OCSPManagerHTTP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.688-03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.688-03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-04T09:20:46.688-03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

When I try $mongo :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Comment: The second command with `--dbPath` seems to have worked according to your logs. It doesn't show any errors. Have you tried connecting to the database and running some queries? Please provide more info like how are you connecting to this database etc

Comment: When I try to start console I receive the mensagem:

MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

Answer (score 0):

The output from the second command isn't an error. The final lines of the logs show that it's listening for connections.

Comment: Yes, but I think is an error to show a log every time I write mongod on terminal.

Comment: It is not an error. If you want to reduce the logging you can run mongod with the [quiet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-quiet) flag. @ThiagoXimenes